# How to remain signed in with Firebase auth() when redirecting to another page?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

After I logged in in index.html, I redirected the page to localhost:8000/userhome.html. However, the auth() status seems like it is no longer signed in. When I try to console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser) in userhome.html, it printed null. I also tried to set persistence to LOCAL when I signed in, it still shows the same thing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Keep an eye on [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/462) for an easier way to get the authenticated user

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to determine when the signed-in user object is available.  It won't be immediately available when a page first loads, even after a successful sign-in that happened on a previous page.  The callback will tell you when it's ready.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
  }
});
```